# How do I subtract a text in order

Tags: php

I want to print a text by dividing by a trailing margin

```php
$text = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text";
$ex = explode(" ",$text);
```

as a result I want:

```
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text  
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy  
Lorem Ipsum is simply  
Lorem Ipsum is  
Lorem Ipsum  
Lorem
```

Comment: Just.... huh? What's a "trailing margin"? What have you tried to achieve this your intended result?

Comment: `foreach { slice; implode; }` or `foreach { implode; array_pop; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

1. Echo the string.

   ```
   echo $text . PHP_EOL;
   ```
2. Remove the last word.

   ```
   $text = substr($text, 0, strrpos($text, ' '));
   ```

Repeat that process until there's no more string.

```
while ($text) {
    echo $text . PHP_EOL;
    $text = substr($text, 0, strrpos($text, ' '));
}
```

This will obviously destroy `$text`, so if you still need it after, make a copy first.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a while loop and strpos to find the positions of the spaces.
Since this will get the string in reverse order from what you want I add it to an array that I can reverse and implode.

```
$text = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text";
$pos = 0;

while($pos = strpos($text, " ", $pos+1)){
    $arr[]= substr($text, 0, $pos);
}
$arr[]= $text;

echo implode("\n", array_reverse($arr));
```

https://3v4l.org/FM2XD